# How to activate fireLESS in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, firebug, less

After installing fireLESS in firefox, how do I activate it.

I can't see any .less on the css dialog when I'm inspecting the element using firebug.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fireless/

Answer (score 1):

Do have the patched version of less from here: [patched version](https://github.com/simonedeponti/less.js) ?

And is this true for you?

> It currently only works if you use LESS in development mode and in browser mode (make sure less.env is set to "development").

Comment: I'm also trying to get this to work. But I dont understand what that means. I've installed the add-on. What do I do next? Where or/how (what code/language) do I set the less.env development mode? I have no clue what to do next /Thanks

Comment: <script>var less = { env : "development"  }; </script> Add this line before the line where you link the less.js script .

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for patched version now as for ver 1.6+ of lessjs , install fireless and put these lines before the line where you link your less.js file .

```
<script>
var less = {
env:"development",
dumpLineNumbers:'mediaquery'
};
</script>
```

eg .

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="style.less" />
<script>
var less = {
env:"development",
dumpLineNumbers:'mediaquery'
};
</script>
<script src="js/less.js"></script>
```

You'll be able to see less css styles along with the line numbers where the style was declared . This works for me .